# How to get real customer ip in google container engine and apache setup

Tags: apache, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I can't find out customer real IP address when apache-php enviroment runs in google container. Without modifying anything, I get ip address from container address range, when using mod_remoteip, I can add

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Client-IP
RemoteIPInternalProxyList ournet/proxy-list
```

and add rows into "proxy-list"-file:

```
10.240.0.0/16 # google internal network
10.244.0.0/14 # Cluster aadress range
```

Only the row 10.244.0.0/14 gives any result. In this case I get the cluster node's ip as REMOTE_ADDR value from the 10.240.0.0/16 network.

It seems, that the node itself acts as forwarder, without adding needed headers to the request or I am looking it from totally wrong perspective?

Answer (score 1):

Some traffic is masqueraded, but it is done at L3, rather than L7, so there's no way to add a header. :(

This will get better soon for in-cluster traffic, but we have to wait for cloud load-balancers to catch up before we can properly handle out-of-cluster traffic properly.

Comment: So there's definitely no way to have the visitor's IP from a PHP application that is running inside of Google Container Engine/Kubernetes ?!

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to be true, unless you implement another layer of load-balancing that exists outside of kubernetes.  We're pushing on cloud load-balancers to support this better.